# Highlightjs with Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, highlightjs

The [ng2-smart-table application documentation](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/demo/demo.component.html) has `code` elements snippets that look like this:

```
<code highlight class="typescript">{{ snippets.require }}</code>
```

The [resulting documentation looks like this](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/demo).

When looking at the resulting application html, it looks like [highlightjs](https://highlightjs.org/) is doing the highlighting, but I don't see an import of an angular dependency that would perform the transform (Or any preprocessing by the scripts), so just wondering how it works?

### Per the Answer

Thought is as really cool how simple this is to do with Angular:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as hljs from 'highlight.js';

@Directive({
selector: 'code[highlight]',
})
export class HighlightCodeDirective implements AfterViewInit {

constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
    hljs.highlightBlock(this.elRef.nativeElement);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the code more closely there is a [highlight](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/cf59d21ee22b244a63ab58a1f1d677ada6f521fe/src/app/shared/directives/highlight.directive.ts) [directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) (ng2-smart-table/src/app/shared/directives/highlight.directive.ts) that uses highlightjs. It is part of the sample application not the library so you need to copy it if you want to do the same in your application.